# Having trouble coming up with a 'display function' or added functionality - c

Tags: c, function, printf

Finishing up a program and been told that I need to have the `cards` be displayed after the user quits.

Tried having `draw` return the `hand` variable and printing that, and storing each result of the `draw()`, which I had turned to int; although I am showing you the working function,  which is void.

So far nothing works and I am lost.

```
void draw(int deck[SIZE], int a) {
    int numCards = 10;
    int i; 
    int hand[numCards];
    int card;
    for(i = 0; i < numCards && top > 0; i++) {
        card = deck[top-1];     
        hand[i] = card; 
        top--;   
    }
    if(a != 0) {
        printcards(card);
    } else {
        for(i = 0; i < numCards && top > 0; i++)
        printcards(card);
    }
}
```

Program can print off cards as drawn and edited version looks like:

```
int draw(int deck[SIZE], int a) {
    int numCards = 10;
    int i; 
    int hand[numCards];
    int card;
    for(i = 0; i < numCards && top > 0; i++) {
        card = deck[top-1];     
        hand[i] = card; 
        top--;   
    }
    if(a != 0) {
        printcards(card);
    } else {
        for(i = 0; i < numCards && top > 0; i++)
        printcards(card);
    }
    return card; /* or return hand */
}
void printcards(int card) {
    char suits[4][9] = {
        "Hearts",
        "Diamonds",
        "Clubs",
        "Spades"
    };
    if(card%13 == 0 || card%13 == 10 || card%13 == 11 || card%13 == 12) {
        printf("%s ", facecheck(card%13) );
    } else {
        printf("%d ", card%13+1);
    }
    printf("of %s \n", suits[card/13]);
}
```

This function is the actual printing of cards:

```
void players(int deck[]) {
    int x;
    int a; 
    int yourhand[10];

    a = 1;

    printf("Player 1 \n"); 
    printf("Your Hand is: \n"); 
    draw(deck, a);
    draw(deck, a);
    while(a == 1) {
        printf("What would you like to do: Press 1 to Draw. 2 to Stay. \n"); 
        scanf("%d" , &x); 
        if(x == 1) {
            draw(deck, a);
        } else { 
            a--;
        }
    }
}
```

This function calls the `draw()` with user input, then need to add a `display()` after the else, before `a--` or store result of draw into your hand and print result. So far nothing has worked.

Comment: You want the card variable to 'stick around' after the draw so that it  printed later?  Try malloc'ing the card returned from the `int draw()` which you change to `int *draw()` and storing it in a yourhand which holds 10 int pointers instead of just ten ints.  Then after your "a--" you can walk the elements of yourhand to print them using the printcards() or a funciton that formats the whole hand.  Remember to dealloc the contents of yourhand when you're done with it.

Comment: Please provide the complete code so we can compile and test.